# PHP jQuery AJAX problems

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I have a jQuery AJAX issue.
my problem is when i call a page from ajax, it loads fine
One of the characters, the apostrophe turns into �
I do not understand why?

Output: "of course it�s based on the"

its supposed to be "of course it’s based on the"

Why is Ajax doing this? Is there a solution?

Comment: Are you specifying utf-8 as your charset in a meta tag in your html output?

Comment: Might be a character encoding problem...make sure you're using UTF-8.

Comment: probably not a standard apostrophe character, and you've got a charset mistmatch between the ajax output and the web page's. e.g. ajax is spitting out cp-1252 but your page is utf-8.

Comment: <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">

Comment: @marc u are right.... problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved. I had copied this from another source. So I just copied and pasted the whole paragraph in notepad, Deleted the character and then retyped the character. and it work.